# Staircase Pattern Printing in c++

Tags: c++, string

```
void staircase(int n)
{
for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
{
    string h(i,'#');
    string s(n-i,' ');   
    cout<<s<<h<<endl;
}}
```

Please explain the first two lines in the for loop. Can we declare like `string h(i,'#');` in strings?

Does it means filling the `i`th position in the string with "#"?

Comment: There are three lines in the for loop. Which two are you asking about?

Comment: 1st two lines in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we declare like string h(i,'#'); in strings?

Yes. Actually, that's ***defining*** the string, **not *declaring***.

> Does it means filling the ith position in the string with "#"?

No.

Please use the reference pages. They are and will be your friend in the C++ journey.

For your particular use case, [refer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) to the constructor of `std::string` especially this one

[image: Constructor]

which has this description

> 2. Constructs the string with count copies of character ch.

These are the `std::string` constructors used in your code. So `std::string h(i,'#')` constructs a string with `i` copies of `#`. Same logic for `std::string s(n-i,' ')`.